# bring page to foreground? multipage editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, multipage

I'm develpping an RCP user interface. I have a multipage editor in which pages are editors (EditorPart). From a first page in my multipage editor I want to open a second one if a button is pressed. I've managed to do that but the problem that I'm facing is that the created page is visible only if we switch to it, i.e only the tab is visble.. what I want is to directly switch to the new page automatically after its creation. In other words, how can I bring the new page to foreground exactly when it is created.

Can you help me please
Kind Regards,
Jean

Comment: Seems to me a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447324/add-and-display-a-new-formpage-to-a-formeditor-using-a-command

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the calling the method `org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(int)` should do the trick.